# Prove the diffentiability of a function of a continous function at x=0.

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, continuity

If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x=0$, prove that $g(x)=xf(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

---

So this is the definition of a continuous function:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0)$$

And I need to prove that this limit exists:
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{(x+h)-x}$$

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(x+h)f(x+h)-xf(x)}{h}$$

At the point $x=0$:

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(h)f(h)}{h}$$

$$= f(0)$$

My question is, where do I use the fact that f(x) is continuous? Is it to go from the second to last result to the last result?

And is my answer correct?

Comment: Your approach is correct. The continuity of $f$ is used in the very last step.

Comment: Another usage is that $xf(x) \to 0 (x\to 0)$ This requires $f$ to be bounded around $0$, wich is overfulfilled for $f$ continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specifically answer the question you asked, when you wrote $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(h)f(h)}{h} = f(0)$ presumably you cancelled the factor of $h$, and then $\lim_{h\to 0} f(h)=f(0)$ precisely because of the continuity of $f$ at $0$.  (Note that $f$ could be discontinuous everywhere else, and the argument would still be valid.)

Answer (score 1):

To be shown is that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{g\left(x\right)-g\left(0\right)}{x-0}$$
exists.

Note that for $x\neq 0$: $$\frac{g\left(x\right)-g\left(0\right)}{x-0}=\frac{xf\left(x\right)}{x}=f\left(x\right)$$
Indeed $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f\left(x\right)$ exists (and equalizes $f\left(0\right)$).

This as a consequence of the fact that $f$ is continuous at $0$.